# can not install skype

Tags: skype

```
sudo dpkg - skype-ubuntu*.deb
[sudo] password for user: 
dpkg: error: need an action option


Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
```

I got this output when  try to install Skype on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: look at my answer [here](C:\Users\Abed\Pictures\Ubuntu\2013-06-02_1259.png) on how to install Skype.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think you're meant to type: `sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu*.deb` no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead 
`sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu*.deb` It should now work without any error.